# JavaScript if statement running both conditions if location replace used

Tags: javascript

I have the following if statement that looks for a hash on document ready (this code NEVER runs again on the page). And if there is no hash then add one using replace, so that it doesn't trigger a hashchange event.

```
if( window.location.hash == '' ) {

    console.log('no hash');

    location.replace(location.href.replace(/\/?$/, '#/section-0/page-0')); // change the url without creating a hashchange

} else {

    console.log('has hash');

}
```

However if I visit the page with no hash, what I will see in the console is `has hash` and the replace will have happened... **how is this possible? as that console log is in a different part of the statement.** If I comment out the replace then it only falls into the first part of the if statement. How can it jump into the if statement do the replace (but ignoring the first console log) and then jump into the second part?

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying doesn't make sense.

I tried to make a full example from your code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function x()
    {
        if( window.location.hash == '' )
        {
            console.log('no hash');
            location.replace(location.href.replace(/\/?$/, '#/section-0/page-0')); // change the url without creating a hashchange

            alert('changed!');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('has hash');
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:x()">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This code executes as follows when opening default:

1. Click button
2. Console `no hash`
3. Alert
4. Click button
5. Console `has hash`

If you put the code without function declaration inside the body (so it always executes), like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        if( window.location.hash == '' )
        {
            console.log('no hash');
            location.replace(location.href.replace(/\/?$/, '#/section-0/page-0')); // change the url without creating a hashchange

            alert('changed!');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('has hash');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows:

1. Console `no hash`
2. Alert

Comment: @Cameron: need more help?